# How to avoid Out of memory error in this loop in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I am loading files from filelistbox. When the file number in filelistbox is large, the program prompts "out of memory". How to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

**[Edited]**

```
public
...
List: Tstringlist;
...


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List:=tstringlist.create;
  List.sorted:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.processfile;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  if filelistbox1.Count =0 then exit;
  for i:=0 to filelistbox1.count-1 do // 10000 files in filelistbox1
  begin
    memo1.clear;
    memo1.lines.loadfromfile(DirectoryListBox1+'\'+
      filelistbox1.Items.Strings[i]);  
    Addinlist;
    List.savetofile(afile);  
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Addinlist;

var
  w1: string;
  p1: tperlregex;
begin
  List.clear;
  p1:=tperlregex.Create(nil) ;
  p1.Subject:=memo1.text;
  p1.regex:='\w+';
  while p1.MatchAgain do 
  begin
    w1:=p1.MatchedExpression;
    List.add(w1);
  end;
  freeandnil(p1);
end;


Windows task manager memory displays: (approxomate number)

file number reaches 10, used memory 402M
file number reaches 100, used memory 402M
file number reaches 500, used memory 408M
file number reaches 1000, used memory 412M
file number reaches 1600, used memory 432M
file number reaches 2200, used memory 460M
file number reaches 3000, used memory 500M
file number reaches 5500, used memory 650M // prompts "Out of memory", form1 freez
```

This is on Delphi 7. My questions are:

```
Does List.clear method clean memory? 
Is there number limit to the items in stringlist?
Can you please let me know how to solve it?
```

Comment: You are probably fragmenting address space. Since you didn't show all of the code, we don't know what the code that is hidden from us is doing. If you had posted a program that we could run, then we could reproduce and help you. Why did you choose to make it difficult by hiding code? For sure, you need to cut down the code to a manageable portion. And yes, that will take you time. So, take the time, cut it down, and let us have a complete program that we can work with.

Comment: Plus let the code be without compile-time errors.  I can't say that TMemo has changed, but I'm 99% sure it shouldn't have between D3 and D7.  I had to correct much of what you posted.  I replaced "memo1.lines.loadfromfile(filelistbox1.Items.Strings[i]);" with " memo1.Lines.Assign(filelistbox1.Items);" to fix one of the more grievous run-time errors, for instance.  This may be the problem.

Comment: @Glenn1234 It did change. And your proposal completely changes the meaning. The code in the question loads the contents of files specified by file names in FileListBox1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I see the problem, it was unrelated and the code example I have sitting here is fine (minus the other compile-time errors of course).

Comment: Repeated matching on Memo1.Text sounds bad. Try avoiding the Text property and instead match line by line. Avoiding regex altogether may help too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you so much. I am testing your suggestion. why avoiding regex may help?

Comment: Don't know. Perhaps a memory leak in the regex code? Try stripping parts of your code out and see how behaviour changes. Try replacing the regex match loop with code that adds random words, as many words as file length div 4 say. Try to isolate the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks again. I am isolating that part for separate test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does List.clear method clean memory?

Yes, `TStringList.Clear` method frees memory allocated by strings

> Is there number limit to the items in stringlist?

No, there is no practical limit.

> Can you please let me know how to solve it?

No, because it is impossible to say does the code

```
List.clear;
...
...// parse each word in memo1;
List.add(eachwordinmemo1);
```

leak or not.